Custom maven build plugin to be used in microservices
I have multiple Spring Boot microservices and I am trying to implement a common component for building all these microservices. For example, this component will be having common dependencies, plugins for code quality (pmd,checkstyle) etc. So that, I don't need to have these common configurations to be repeated in all the microservices instead just integrate this common component only.
I tried this in Gradle with the help of this documentation: https://medium.com/javarevisited/custom-gradle-plugin-for-unified-static-code-analysis-c8c4cc0df078
Now my question is, with Maven is it possible? I tried to build a custom Maven plugin but looks like it is not intended for doing this build process.
Could you please suggest on this?

You can define those default configuration and check (pmd, checkstyle etc.) via a Parent POM (corporate pom)... which then will be used in your microservices...

Okay @khmarbaise is this the only possible approach with Maven?
